# KDB windowed join or bin usage to compare records within timerange

Tags: kdb

I have a trade snapshot where I intend to scan other rows within 5 secs window for trades which have matching economics and based on this I want to tag the trade snapshot

```
TradeId,Time,CcyPair,BrokerId,Amount
ABC1 ,00:00:03.001,GBPUSD,X,100
ABC2 ,00:00:17.009,USDINR,Y,111
ABC3,00:00:07.006, GBPUSD,X,-100
```

Trades 1 and 3 are within 5 secs and belong to same brokerid and currency pair and have equal and opposite amount.

Results Expected.

```
TradeId,Time,CcyPair,BrokerId,Amount, Indicator
ABC1 ,00:00:03.001,GBPUSD,X,100,Offset
ABC2 ,00:00:17.009,USDINR,Y,111,NotOffset
ABC3,00:00:07.006, GBPUSD,X,-100,Offset
```

Comment: If there's no other contributions here on SO you should reply with Ajay's answer from the k4 listbox/topicbox, which looks like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I got from forum.

```
update Indicator:?[;`Offset;`Notoffset]0= 
(sum;Amount)fby([]BrokerId;CcyPair;bin[;Time]min[Time]+5000*til count i) from t
```